# How to extract key and values from given json file in perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to get key value pairs from following data. I am using this codee , however i am not getting any output . please suggest

```
use lib qw( ..);
use LWP::Simple;
use JSON;
my $filename = '/file.txt';
my $data;
if (open (my $json_str, $filename))
{
  local $/ = undef;
  my $json = JSON->new;
  $data = $json->decode(<$json_str>);
  close($json_stream);
}
print $data->{name};

__DATA__
{
   “org1” : {
  “repo1” : [
     “John”,
     “Sam”,
     “Sammy”,
  ],
  “org2” : [
     “repo2”,
     “Samn”,
     “Laggy”,
     “Tester”,
      ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Please enable [`warnings` and `strict` pragmas](https://perlmaven.com/always-use-strict-and-use-warnings) to see errors in your code. Are you sure `$filename` has a slash in front? Should it be `file.txt` and not `/file.txt`. Also `$json_stream` should probably `$json_str`?

Comment: Thanks for checking.  my actual json file content is __DATA__ . I am looking for extract the keys and velus from above data. Thank you.

Comment: In order to use the DATA handle, you need to read from the DATA handle. Your code reads from a file in the root directory of your computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can read the JSON data:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use JSON;

my $str = do { local $/; <DATA> };
my $json = JSON->new;
my $data = $json->decode($str);
print Dumper($data);

__DATA__
{
   "org1" : {
       "repo1" : [
           "John",
           "Sam",
           "Sammy"
       ]
   },
   "org2" : {
       "repo2" :[
           "Samn",
           "Laggy",
           "Tester"
       ]
   }
}
```

**Output**:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'org2' => {
                      'repo2' => [
                                   'Samn',
                                   'Laggy',
                                   'Tester'
                                 ]
                    },
          'org1' => {
                      'repo1' => [
                                   'John',
                                   'Sam',
                                   'Sammy'
                                 ]
                    }
        };
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Could you please suggest how to get the results like 'org2->repo2->samn' and org1->repo1->john .

Comment: Thanks. i am getting this error `Can't coerce array into hash at 2.pl line 9, <DATA> line 1` . i've tried like  print $data->{org2}{repo2}{Samn}. . I am actually looking for getting  values from above org2 and org1  . like  'sam', 'laggy', 'Tester'  and 'John','sam',sammy' .

Comment: Ok, sorry my bad I thought `repo2` was hash but of course it is an array! Try `$data->{org2}{repo2}[0]` to access the first element of the array `repo2`